# Make self.view a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I'm experimenting with a TabBarController and the default project creates the UITabBarController and also gives you two view controllers.

I want the view of one of these view controllers to be a UIScrollView, i.e. when calling `self.view` on `FirstViewController` I want to get back a `UIScrollView *` and not just a `UIView *`.

The view controller gets initialised with `initWithNibName:` but I can't see anything assigning the view property in there.

If this all sounds a bit weird, maybe I'm doing this wrong? I realise I can drop a UIScrollView onto the view that's already created with me, but it just seemed a bit pointless to have a parent view in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame....];
    self.view = scrollView;`

Comment: @janusfidel Thanks for your response. That would work if I was creating my view programatically, but I'd like to use interface builder.

Comment: @janusfidel and OP -- I don't suggest you do this. Extremely bad practice. You should create a new scrollview, add it as subview of self.view, then access it using, e. g., its tag property or whatever.

Comment: @H2CO3 its not bad practice to do it this way, but you should put that code in loadView

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just realised how to do this.

I can do a cast in my code to make UIView a UIScrollView. Like so...

```
UIScrollView *tempScrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.view;
tempScrollView.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
```

Then, in Interface Builder, you can use the inspector to set a custom class for your UIView. I set the class as UIScrollView in here and all seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use interface builder. Just load up your nib, delete the view on the left panel, and drag a UIScrollView into the area.

Next link from Files Owner to the new UIScrollView as the view property.

The only downside to doing it this way is in your code, whenever you want specific `UIScrollView` functions you will have to typecast the view property (using `(UIScrollView *)self.view` ), or put it in a variable like so

```
 UIScrollView *sview = self.view;
 //Then use sview for your changes
```

The best way would be to do it in code however.